# How to optimize threshold in pocketsphinx.js

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, pocketsphinx

**In original folder of pocketsphinx.js, where should I add the threshold code? I added to recognizer.js but didnt work. Here is the code that i found:**

```
["-kws_threshold", '2']
```

**I added like this (into recognizer.js):**

```
function initialize(data, clbId) {
var config = new Module.Config();
config.push_back(["-kws_threshold", '300']);
```

**And [this](https://github.com/syl22-00/pocketsphinx.js-lib) is README of pocketsphinx..**
**Thank you**

Answer (score 2):

You need to optimize it on desktop with a prerecorded audio file, see details from the [tutorial](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutoriallm)

Threshold must be specified for every keyphrase. For shorter keyphrase you can use smaller thresholds like 1e-1, for longer threshold must be bigger, up to 1e-50. If your keyphrase is very long, larger than 10 syllables, it is recommended to split it and spot for parts separately. For the best accuracy it is better to have keyphrase with 3-4 syllables. Too short phrases are easily confused.

Threshold must be tuned to balance between false alarms and missed detections, the best way to tune threshold is to use a prerecorded audio file. Tuning process is the following:

- Take a long recording with few occurrences of your keywords and some
  other sounds. You can take a movie sound or something else. The
  length of the audio should be approximately 1 hour
- Run keyword
  spotting on that file with different thresholds for every keyword

Use the following command:

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -infile <your_file.wav> -keyphrase <"your keyphrase"> -kws_threshold <your_threshold> -time yes
```

- It will print many lines, some of them are keywords with detection times and confidences. You can also disable extra logs with `-logfn your_file.log` option to avoid clutter.
- From keyword spotting results count how many false alarms and missed
  detections you've encountered Select the threshold with smallest
  amount of false alarms and missed detections